# Add menu in customer account navigation magento

Tags: magento, menu, navigation

can anyone tell me how to add a new menu in customer account navigation (the one in the left). I already saw a lot of posts on how to add links to that, but I want to add a menu, not just a link. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution link 
**http://inchoo.net/magento/managing-navigation-links/**
which is help you to add/remove links in customer account navigation on left side bar. so refer it and do it. hope it helps :)